# Safe to put 'build.gradle-e' in .gitignore?

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gitignore

After one of the recent upgrades of Android Studio and/or the Gradle plugin, I've noticed that a build.grade-e file is created after I edit a build.gradle file.  The build.gradle-e file is a copy of the pre-edited copy of build.gradle and I assume it is simply a backup.

Trying to google this filename has been difficult since Google ignores the hyphen.

Since build.gradle-e seems to be a backup, I don't see a need to introduce it into my git repository.

Is is safe/good to add build.gradle-e to my .gitignore?

Comment: Are you using [this project](https://github.com/timurstrekalov/saga) in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing that comes from plain gradle, so I suggest it is some sort of working copy used by the android studio. I definitely would add it to .gitignore. Even better it sounds like an issue in Android studio for me.

Comment: I feel like the Gradle plugin for Android Studio is responsible, I just wish I could get confirmation.  Adding it to .gitignore has become a logical conclusion, but now I'm curious what the story is with this new behavior.

Comment: Turns out the culprit was a bash script I wrote that modified build.gradle. In OS X if you type `sed -i -e [stuff]` instead of `sed -i '' -e [stuff]` you get a backup of the file you're modifying with -e appended to the end. Nonetheless, thanks @Rene!